# Get the difference of columns in percentage pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have measurements made two times

```
ix    m_t1   m_t2
1     42     84
2     12     12
3     100    0
```

I am trying to get the relative difference (percent of growth) between the first and second measurement

Desired result

```
ix    difference%
1     50
2     0
3     ???
```

How can I obtain it? And what to do in the third case?

Comment: You need to be clear on relative difference here. 42 to 84 is 100% difference, and 84 to 42 is 50%... you display just 50

Comment: @roganjosh in fact, 84 to 42 is -50%.

Comment: @sentence sure, not gonna argue with that. I can't think of a reasonable metric that results in just `50` in the output and the OP doesn't know how to handle the last set of values; I suspect this is just a math question more than anything - it depends what they want to represent.

Comment: @roganjosh OP talks about _percent of growth_. I go for Occam's razor: math error.

Comment: Thank you all for clarification, then I need 100 as a result. Why do I receive minuses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `pct_change()`:

```
df = df[['m_t2', 'm_t1']].pct_change(axis=1).mul(100)[['m_t1']]
df.columns = ['difference%']

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    difference%
ix             
1    -50.000000
2      0.000000
3           inf
```